# What's the translation of a login wall in French?

Tags: traduction, internet

According to [Google Generative AI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eZRd.png):

> A login wall, also known as an auth wall, is a UI antipattern that prevents users from viewing or using a site until they log in.

I confirm that the definition is correct. Example: X (formerly, Twitter).

What's the translation of a login wall in French?

[Google Translate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCzz4.png) says it's "mur de connexion" but I don't see any occurrences of "mur de connexion" on Google. Also, I don't see any translation on [linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=login+wall+).

Comment: Considering that it's a pretty new thing (to enter the mainstream, anyway), it would be surprising if corpus-based translation like Google Translate had it as a real collocation instead of an ad-hoc pairing like they do here.

Comment: @LukeSawczak True, but  Google Generative AI is also corpus-based. (but yes,  a collocation is less likely than a single occurrence and genAI does have a bit of pseudo-reasoning ability).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Pseudo-reasoning for a pseudo-intelligence. Ask ChatGPT for a mathematical proof, see what you get.

Comment: @Frank Thanks, yes ChatGPT has limitations eg  https://aclanthology.org/2023.findings-emnlp.878.pdf

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt For that reason, I would be no more confident that "login wall" is the term in English based on GGAI's evidence alone.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I can speak English, I confirm the term exists in English.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I can speak English, I can't confirm the existence of technical terms not in my domain. :) But indeed, I'm happy to accept the premise that it's the correct term on the strength of those who live and work with it, just not on AI alone. (As in, I'm not contesting that the term exists for the purpose of the question, just the methodology.)

Comment: @LukeSawczak Got it, my bad, "According to" is not a good choice.

Comment: For what it's worth, as a native English speaker working in tech, I would not have understood "login wall". It might be common in specific communities but I very much doubt your average English speaker would understand it without an explanation. Even _paywall_, a far more common term is unlikely to be understood outside the geekosphere.

Comment: For these kinds of technical terms, your best bet would normally be to look at France Term: https://www.culture.fr/franceterme/ ; however in this case I couldn't find anything called an "auth wall" or "login wall". But then I have never heard these expressions used in English either, so they might not be common enough to have a translation. There are translations for "login", "auth", "paywall", but not for "auth wall" nor "login wall".

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt when you ask "*What's the translation*" it sounds like you assume there is one at all. Are you asking for what the translation *should be*? Because most of the time for recent terms like this one, there is simply no translation yet. What type of answer are you looking for? "There is none." or an attempt at a translation? Even the best attempt at someone from this site it not very useful if nobody uses it elsewhere.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat  I'm familiar with the empty set. No translation is a valid answer.

Comment: Yeah generative IA are not even pseudo-reasoning, they don't reason at all (yet), they are still a predictive text generation based on statistical data and the current conversation. IMO in the question, it got it wrong saying it's an antipattern (a trendy word in the nowadays coding world). It's actually a pattern, and a valid one

Comment: @Kaddath it is absolutely an antipattern from a UX perspective if the information behind the login wall is public.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'**Firewall**' is either used untranslated or translated to ***pare-feu***.

The more recent '**paywall**' which is close to 'login wall' is also often left untranslated or can occasionally be named ***barrière de péage***. The OQLF suggests ***Verrou d'accès payant***.

'**Login wall**' is even more recent. I would use a periphrasis like *page/site **protégé par authentification***, *[...] qui **impose une authentification*** or better *[...] **ne permettant pas un accès anonyme***. Extrapolating from the OQLF, we might also attempt ***Verrou d'accès authentifié***.

There is also '**cookie wall**', as [commented by XouDo](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54083/whats-the-translation-of-a-login-wall-in-french/54086?noredirect=1#comment115301_54086). I don't venture translating it, risking to add another *[tournure ampoulée](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/54089/1109)* to my reply ;-)

Comment: il est intéressant de noter qu'il existe aussi un terme de cookie wall (voir https://blog.poool.fr/fr/un-cookie-wall-cest-quoi-definition-exemples-et-bonnes-pratiques/), l'horrible popup qui nous empêche de visualiser tout ou partie d'une page tant qu'on n'a pas accepté/refusé les fameux traceurs de navigation.

Comment: France Term suggests "péage de lecture numérique" and doesn't even mention "barrière de péage". I wouldn't suggest "barrière de péage" either, since this is universally understood as the place at the entrance or exit of a motorway where drivers have to stop to take a ticket or pay, so unless you're intentionally making a pun or metaphor, using "barrière de péage" to mean something else is just going to confuse your readers.

Comment: Is it not "pare" rather than "par"?

Comment: @Stef Je n'ai pas écrit que *barrière de péage* était suggéré par France Terme qui propose néanmoins *péage*. Est-ce que les lecteurs seraient troublés par ce terme ? Je n'en suis pas sûr, on a bien pendant longtemps parlé des autoroutes de l'information, les péages vont bien avec...

Comment: @Simd It's *pare* (shield) in *pare-feu* but *par* in *par authentification* (by authentication.)

Answer (score 4):

La solution d'une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/54086) « ne permettant pas un accès anonyme » est excellente à mon avis. Je trouve qu'il s'agit d'un faux problème ; un bien sur un site de vente est-il derrière un « paywall », mon compte courriel est-il derrière un « login wall » ?? Tout contenu doit-il être accessible sans s'authentifier ni payer quoi que ce soit ?? La cooccurrence en langue anglaise va toujours être « *behind* a X wall » et je ne saisis pas quel contexte hormis une vedette dans une liste de termes exigerait de manier le terme indépendamment de tout contexte de phrase. Si on veut parler d'*entraves* à l'accès anonyme on peut le faire dans une discussion. Donc à mon avis une périphrase ressemblant à la définition du terme suffit :

> Contenu [désormais][malheureusement] accessible uniquement en s'authentifiant/après s'être
> authentifié/par authentification/avec un compte.

S'il ne l'était pas auparavant et qu'on veut porter un jugement sur le fait qu'il le soit maintenant, on peut utiliser « désormais » et « malheureusement ». Si un développeur discute de ça et qu'il décide d'ajouter cet élément au site/à la page, il peut décider me *mettre une authentification* pour accéder au contenu, de *demander à l'utilisateur de* créer un compte/de s'authentifier.

Comment: I suppose there is a difference between "ne permettant pas un accès anonyme" and "ne permettant pas un accès sans login". Websites like impots.gouv.fr or your bank or your internet provider require you to identify yourself; most other websites ask for an email address but don't require you to use your real name.

Comment: And then there is a whole spectrum: some websites force you to create an account but don't ask for additional identifying personal information (except maybe an email address - this used to be optional but now almost every website forces you to give one in order to create an account); and some websites initially don't ask for additional personal information, but eventually coerce you into giving a phone number (like leboncoin.fr)

Comment: @Stef There is a difference indeed, but I construe _accès anonyme_ as not requiring anything and don't consider providing an email as an access that is anonymous. Some sites ask you to verify your age because it's adult content, but I don't consider it a "login wall" in any case. Will it be an "age wall"? ;-) I don't see how a requirement is a wall per se. People may not like it, there may be more of it today, but it is what it is. Huge corporations ask you to provide tons of info and then you access their different components using these creds in a transparent fashion. "Inital wall" I guess.

Comment: @Plusjamaisquoiencore comme l'indique la question, c'est le "login wall" en tant qu'*antipattern* dont il s'agit. C'est à dire une mauvaise pratique d'expérience utilisateur guidée par des buts commerciaux ou une habitude un peu idiote. On se situe implicitement dans un contexte où les informations affichées après le login wall sont publiques et non confidentielles, si elles l'étaient, cela demanderait bien sûr légitimement une authentification.

Comment: @guillaume31 Le contenu journalistique est-il public ? Je comprends la nuance, mais quand je suis connecté avec un identifiant unique sur un compte de courriel Gmail, je suis connecté aussi dans Google Search. Les résultats de recherche sont-ils publics ou confidentiels ?? Il y a une bonne expérience parce que la pratique consiste à authentifier dans l'un et que ça vaut dans tout leur écosystème. Un site indépendant met-il de l'avant un antipattern comme il ne dispose pas d'écosystème ou parce qu'il ne demandait pas d'authentification auparavant ? On peut nuancer ta nuance et se demander...

Comment: @guillaume31 ...jusqu'à quel point elle n'est pas tributaire d'une position de monopole ou d'une position où ces monopoles présentent « gratuitement », soit dans leurs résultats, soit dans leur interface ou dans leur IA, un contenu qui n'est pas leur propriété intellectuelle mais avec lesquels ils génèrent des revenus publicitaires. Tout en habituant leurs utilisateurs à considérer que ces contenus devraient être gratuits ou que la propriété intellectuelle est mal. Or à mon avis il n'en est rien et un rééquilibrage de ces réalités est inévitable. _Food for thought_.

Comment: @Plusjamaisquoiencore l'expression sous-entend que c'est du contenu public qui pourrait très bien être accessible gratuitement sans login. Ce qui est reproché, c'est de faire du *people farming* en récoltant le maximum de comptes utilisateurs et de données possibles pour les monétiser. Ou d'être trop paresseux pour faire un système qui gère à la fois les visiteurs anonymes et les membres connectés.

Comment: @Plusjamaisquoiencore après, on est d'accord que l'expression n'est pas très parlante en elle-même et peut susciter beaucoup de mauvaises interprétations. Et je suis le premier à déplorer les nombreux termes galvaudés ou vidés de leur sens par la communauté tech.

Answer (score 0):

**jlliagre** a compris le problème mais s'égare dans des tournures ampoulées;
**Plus jamais quoi encore**, lui, relève très justement qu'il s'agit d'un faux problème, à quoi j'ajoute: fruit d'un concept linguistique farfelu, émanant de cerveaux contemporains — probablement américains — qui s'évertuent à inventer quand les bases font défaut… Tout un programme!

Pour rester simple, et s'il faut vraiment traduire cette ineptie, on aura le choix entre "Accès par mot de passe" ou "Accès réservé", ou, par périphrase: "[pour consulter le site, utiliser l'application, etc.] l'utilisateur doit fournir un mot de passe [ou être agréé, ou avoir créé un compte, etc.]

C'est une ineptie, car l'utilisateur comprendra sur-le-champ ce qu'on attend de lui, ineptie parce que ça revient à recommander à l'acheteur d'une voiture d'y mettre du carburant s'il veut qu'elle fonctionne (je suis resté bloqué sur le "thermique", on ne m'en voudra pas).

À ceux qui tiennent l'anglais pour une langue dont la traduction s'opère directement (genre potache de quinze ans qui recourt au *Harraps* anglais-français), je conseille de jeter un coup d'œil (et plus) au *Lexique analogique* de Jacques Dubé ou à l'admirable *Guide français de la traduction anglais français* de René Meertens.

Comment: Les "login walls" sont une réalité, sinon en tant que technique commerciale d'acquisition d'utilisateurs assumée, au moins comme phénomène observable qui s'est étendu depuis les débuts d'internet. Qui plus est, je doute que le *Guide de la traduction* autorise un traducteur à se passer de traduire une notion qu'il réfute ou conteste personnellement...

Comment: c'est pas du tout une ineptie, pour le cas de twitter ça a causé pas mal de bruit justement. Le site était anciennement accessible par n'importe qui, et Elon Musk a unilatéralement décidé de forcer n'importe qui à avoir un compte pour voir le moindre tweet, ce qui a énervé plein de monde et a été considéré comme une très mauvaise décision (ça n'augmente pas beaucoup le nombre de création de compte et ça supprime beaucoup de visibilité à la plateforme. En plus d'être désagréable pour tout le monde). Il l'a ensuite désactivé discrètement. Il est tout à fait à-propos d'avoir un mot dédié.

Comment: J'aurais aimé que Musk conserve ça, moi qui tente depuis des années de décourager les politiques d'utiliser son égout pour diffuser des informations de notoriété publique aux justiciables... là je pouvais dire que l'accès n'était pas _universel_. Je suis sûr que j'aurai d'autres occasions de les convaincre.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat — Il ne s'agit pas de bien-fondé, mais de traduction. Vous n'avez rien dit à ce sujet. Que vous soyez d'accord ou non avec le principe ne change rien à la question soulevée.

Comment: @guillaume31 — J'ai émis une opinion personnelle, mais j'ai bien et bien proposé plusieurs traductions. Lisez plus attentivement.